# Time Zone offset number in Objective-c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, time, nstimezone

How can I get the Timezone offset in Objective-C (for iPhone OS 3)?

For example, `GMT -5` is US Eastern Time. I want the `-5` part of it. How would I do so?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
[[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] secondsFromGMT] / 3600
```

Comment: Which, believe it or not, comes from the incredibly useful `NSTimeZone` class.

Comment: What datatype does that return?

Comment: But how to get it for a country like India GMT + 5.30?

Comment: For +5:30, use `[[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] secondsFromGMT] / 3600.0` you will get 5.500